# Unable to get the selected value from drop down in ionic

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am trying to get the value of selected option but I am getting undefined value. Here is the html part:

Minutes
        Days
        weeks
        Item

Here is the type script part:

```
    unitMetric(mySelect) {
    console.log("Selected:",mySelect);
  }
```

Comment: is `change` firing?

Comment: yes it is firing

Comment: have you tried my code?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using `Ionic 1`.
Change your code to this:

```
<select ng-Model="selectedUnit" ng-change="unitMetric(selectedUnit)" > 
    <option value="minutes">Minutes</option>
    <option value="days">Days</option>
    <option value="weeks">weeks</option>
    <option value="item">Item</option>
  </select>
</ion-label>
```

Must declare `selectedUnit` in your `ts` file.
Then in the controller:-

```
$scope.unitMetric= function(mySelect) {
    console.log(mySelect);
}
```

I hope this helps you!
Happy Coding!!

Answer (score 0):

In Ionic 2/2+ you should use `[(ngModel)]`.

```
  <select [(ngModel)]="selectedUnit" (change)="unitMetric(selectedUnit)" >
    <option value="minutes">Minutes</option>
    <option value="days">Days</option>
    <option value="weeks">weeks</option>
    <option value="item">Item</option>
  </select>
```

To select minutes as `default option` use below code in your component.

```
export class TestCompoent {

  selectedUnit: string;

  constructor() {
    this.selectedUnit = 'minutes';
  }

  unitMetric(mySelect){
    console.log("Selected:",mySelect);
  }
}
```

see my [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-pjdwju?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.ts)